# How to create a partially deformed cable?

Tags: modeling, displacement

John Dickinson asked on Twitter how to create a deformed cable parametrically, as possible.

Here's the origin post:
https://twitter.com/Motionworks/status/1564762544547692544

[image]

Below is my solution how you can solve this.

Comment: Blender Stack Exchange is a platform to help Blender users finding solutions for problems. As you maybe know, there is also a mode to answer own questions directly. But you're right, I forgot to place the actual user question. I've corrected this in my origin post above.

Answer (score 5):

I've used a simple cylinder for the example.
The cable object has some modifiers to create the effect.
The bending in the cable is based on a curve.

You can download the file to see, how I've done it.

Of course there're more solutions and some are more flexible, but my example can be a good solution for the most cases.

**Shot:**
[image]

**File:**
[image]

Comment: I've uploaded 3.2.1 blend files before and tried it now - they are uploaded. I opened your file and saved it again, but it didn't work. Must be something with your file...?

Comment: Checked your file in a text editor against two of my files... my first starts with `BLENDER-v302RENDH   pÀŸ¹V`, the second with `BLENDER-v302RENDH   Ð¹?` (notice the Blender version information at the beginning). But yours starts with `(µ/ý ô =› êÏ¸-RpÕ` and looks completely different overall. Something wrong with this file or your Blender?

Comment: I've found the reason. My file was set to "compressed". Blender saved it compressed. This seem to be a limitation for Blend-Exchange.

Comment: Ah, good to know. I was already wondering why my very simple file was four times larger than yours.